# Error when building AST from C code using DMS GCC parser

Tags: parsing, dmstoolkit

I want to convert a set of C code into an XML file using AST and for that I'm using DMS GCC4 Domain Parser.

However in the command prompt when I enter run `-V` or run DomainParser nothing shows up (neither XML is getting displayed nor the error is thrown!).

It was working fine previously and I have not made any changes to the file settings.

What am I doing wrong?

```
rpalani@ CHE - N14 - 004 / cygdrive / c / Accent / software / DMS - GCC4 - Parser - 2013 - 09 - 06 / DMS - GCC4 - Parser / DMS / Domains / C / GCC4 / Tools / Parser
$ run - v

rpalani@ CHE - N14 - 004 / cygdrive / c / Accent / software / DMS - GCC4 - Parser - 2013 - 09 - 06 / DMS - GCC4 - Parser / DMS / Domains / C / GCC4 / Tools / Parser
$ run DomainParser

rpalani@ CHE - N14 - 004 / cygdrive / c / Accent / software / DMS - GCC4 - Parser - 2013 - 09 - 06 / DMS - GCC4 - Parser / DMS / Domains / C / GCC4 / Tools / Parser
$ run DomainParser++xml C: \dpalapa_test\ map\ dispensing.c

rpalani@ CHE - N14 - 004 / cygdrive / c / Accent / software / DMS - GCC4 - Parser - 2013 - 09 - 06 / DMS - GCC4 - Parser / DMS / Domains / C / GCC4 / Tools / Parser
$ run DomainPraser BitNLogic.c
```

Comment: Please learn how to write sentences, I couldn't understand your question until I edited it.

Comment: 1) You could ask for more help from "support@semanticdesigns.com".  2) If it was "working fine" previously, what changed about the system on which you are running it?  3) What happens when you do "ECHO %ERRORLEVEL% after you do the run command?  4) One cause of "nothing output" is an outright tool crash; MS's reporting of such events is truly bad.  We've seen this happen with various virus detectors/firewalls (which sometimes load additional code into the application space as the program being run is being loaded) eat too many resources; did you add/change those defenses recently?

Comment: ... you might try getting a more recent version of the tool, which has better defenses against the insert-virus-checker-junk-into-my-address-space problem.

Answer (score 2):

From your command prompt, it appears you are running cygwin.

Guessing: you haven't set your PATH properly to pick up "run.exe" from the SemanticDesigns directory.  [Check using "where run"].

Consequence: you are instead picking up cygwin's "run.exe"  (nothing to do with SD's).    Cygwin "run" would start a Windows program in a hidden console window, which would return immediately, showing no output.